# What to do about this question asked by two different people?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So I tried to resolve this myself, but I made some mistakes and thought I'd better bring it up with Meta instead.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4135569/8718143) yesterday. It has an accepted answer, and another answer which is an example of code which results in this issue. I initially thought the answer was posted by the OP, so I flagged the answer as not an answer (it is definitely not an answer, although I suppose to people in the queue it might not seem that way, so the flag was disputed), and tried to edit the sample into the question. This edit was approved and later retracted by the post author.

It should be noted that I only realised that the question asker and the person who provided the code sample were two different people after I submitted the edit, so I decided to let it stand to see what would happen.

I can see why my attempts at fixing the state of the question were rebuffed, but I also find the current state of the question troubling as it doesn't really fit the SO model. One user asked a question, then another user with the same question posted a code example, then an answer was posted attempting to answer both questions.

Am I overthinking this? While I understand that my initial actions might not have been entirely justified, I stand by my view that the two questions should be all in one place, not with one posted as an answer. In any case, I thought I should bring it to the attention of Meta, to see what should be done about it.

Comment: @user2357112 if you look at the comments on the question, the user who posted the second answer says that they're having the same issue and they'll post their code as an answer.

Comment: There are also comments on the second answer that support this conclusion

Comment: Now that you point that out, I see it and agree with your assessment.

Comment: At least somebody didn't cone along and [speak in first person](https://pm.stackexchange.com/posts/23818/revisions) on behalf of the user.

Comment: FWIW, I'd recommend using a custom flag in the future explaining the situtation, rather than NAA. It's not immediately clear it's actually an MVCE, rather than an answer. It would have likely been declined in the mod queue as well.

Comment: @Rob I realised that after as well. It just seemed so obvious to me that it wasn't an answer, although I guess that's in the context of reading the whole question. I'll give my flags greater thought in future.